# Modifying Express.js Request Object

Tags: node.js, express

In express.js, I would like to provide an additional attribute on the request object for each of my URI listeners. This would provide the protocol, hostname, and port number. For example:

```
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.root); // https://12.34.56.78:1324/
});
```

I could of course concatenate req.protocol, req.host, and somehow pass around the port number (seems to be missing from the req object) for each one of my URI listeners, but I'd like to be able to do it in a way that all of them could access this information.

Also, the hostname can vary between request (the machine has multiple interfaces) so I can't just concatenate this string when the application launches.

The goal is to provide URI's to the consumer which point to further resources in this API.

Is there some sort of way to tell Express that I want req objects to have this additional information? Is there a better way to do this than what I'm outlining?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can add a custom middleware that sets the property for each request:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.root = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/';
    next();
});
```

Using [`req.get`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.get) to obtain the `Host` header, which should include the port if it was needed.

Just be sure to add it before:

```
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak it is not constant, if you have more than one domain (for example 'your-app.com', 'your-app.com.ar' and 'your-app.com.br'), it will be necessary to check the domain for each request.

Comment: app.router is deprecated btw

Answer (score 37):

You can extend the `express.request` prototype.

Comment: like require("express").request.prototype.foo = function(){} ?

Comment: Extend express.request just don't apply in this case, unless for some reason https on his root property never change, otherwise you need to use a middleware and get req.protocol... Anyway, if you want to extend request (and thats actually why I found this question) just use express.request.getFooParam  = function () { return this.param('foo'); }

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Logged in to give a thumbs up, no need for middleware when you can go to the root and extend the prototype.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to modify the request object is to add your own middleware function before the app.router declaration.

```
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
      // Edit request object here
      req.root = 'Whatever I want';
      next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
```

This will modify the request object and every route will be able to access *req.root* property, so

```
    app.get('/',function(req, res, next){
      console.log(req.root); // will print "Whatever I want";
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a middleware. Add this to your `app.configure` block:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  req.root = 'WHAT YOU WANT';
  next();
});
```

Every request will go tough this function, and afterwards go to the right url-block thanks to `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Express was designed to support this in the response object, not the request. The response object support custom variables in `res.locals`. See http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals

This is particularly useful for typescript users. The `locals` property is typed `Record<string, any>`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. We are looking for ways to modify request object.

Comment: `res.locals` says it is for **template rendering**... PassportJS, for example, updates the request to add a user field, so this is definitely not correct.