# request params when using Mocha and Chai to test file node.js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

In the code below, I use req.body to get param from request.

Now, I want get param by using req.user (or req.someName, ...) but I don't know how to do this.

```
it.only('updateEmail',function(done){
    chai.request(server)
        .post('updateEmail')
        .send({
          new_email: faker.internet.email()
        })
        .end(function(err, res){
          if (err){
            console.log('err: ', err)
            done()
          }
          else {
            console.log('res: ', res.body)
            done()
          }
        });
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying Express.js Request Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518132/modifying-express-js-request-object)