# Pass Parameter to Function Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

everything good ? I would like to know the best way and if it is possible to send a certain parameter to an express function in the NodeJS.

i wanna pass the string ('admin') or other string that i want to function 'RoleTolen', using my route.

*function verifyToken*

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];
    // Set the token
    req.token = bearerToken;
    // Next middleware
    next();
  } else {
    // Forbidden
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

*function ValidToken*

```
function validToken(req, res, next) {
  jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.SECRET, (err, authData) => {
    if (err) {
      res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

*function RolesToken*

```
function rolesToken(role, req, res, next) {
  var decoded = jwt.decode(req.token);
  if (!decoded.permissions.includes(role)) {
    res.json("sem permissao");
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

*my route*

```
router.post(
  "/posts",
  verifyToken,
  validToken,
  rolesToken("admin"),
  customerController.posts
);
```

Comment: You can send `JSON.stringify(data)` where data is an object.

Comment: i could undestand , could u make a example ?

Comment: Are you trying to send data from client or in the node itself ?

Comment: node itself my friend.

Comment: Ok sorry, i though in the other way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`function rolesToken(role, req, res, next)` is not a proper Express.js route handler, as you already know (and hence the question, I assume).

What you can do is to write your `rolesToken` as a function that returns the actual Express.js compliant handler (function):

```
function rolesToken(role) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    var decoded = jwt.decode(req.token);
    if (!decoded.permissions.includes(role)) {
      res.json("sem permissao");
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: thanks , this work ! i'll try find some videos about NodeJs + Express before ask.

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) 
Define error-handling middleware functions in the same way as other middleware functions, except with four arguments instead of three, specifically with the signature `(err, req, res, next)):`

Therefore your RolesTaken function won't work as expected.

Secondly, you can create a middleware or modify existing one

```
(req, res, next) => {
  //some stuff

   if(req.path == '/posts') req.role= 'admin';
   if(req.path == '/someOtherPath') req.role= 'someRole';

  //some other stuff
}
```

Now you can get the get the role in req.someProp in the your controller middlerware as `req.role`

you would like to [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518132/modifying-express-js-request-object) also

Comment: Thanks ClaxX , i'll use this on other project .