# NodeJS: Update token through router.use

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am validating a token, and then storing the response as cookie to then be used by router.get methods. However, it seems the it doesn't get updated namely due to the request object being out of date and not pointing to the latest cache / cookies.

Been trying several attempts, greatful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

To note: res.send() isn't required as i'm already sending this.

Libraries:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser
NodeJS 14 (Legacy)

```js
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

// Function to generate a random username
function generateRandomUsername() {
  const usernameLength = 8; // You can adjust the length as needed
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let username = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < usernameLength; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    username += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
  }
  return username;
}

app.use('/hello/', function (req, res, next) {
  // Set the username as a cookie named "Username"
  let username = generateRandomUsername();

  res.cookie('Username', username);
  console.log("ROUTE USE: /hello/" + username);

  // Continue to the next middleware or route handler
  next();
});

app.get('/hello/username', function (req, res) {
  // Retrieve the "Username" cookie and display it
  console.log("PATH /hello/username/ " + req.cookies["Username"]);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: I don't get it. `/foo/` is not the same as `/foo/hello` isn't it? And also, you are changing `res.cookie` and `req.cookie` in the second one

Comment: /foo/ is essentially a path, so any router methods containing .get/post etc will go through the middleware of router.use. https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Res is just sending it to the client, so then i use req to obtain it. Thats the problem i'm havign

Comment: I still don't get itm why setting cookie in `res` should also change `req` in the same request?

Comment: Yeah, that's thats what I also concluded to and i agree with you.  I need to essentially figure out a way to update the request object when using `next()`. I don't want to heavily refactor the code due to constraints of time as the existing code is so coupled (Not my code fyi) so trying if possible to see if theres a hotfix or a small work-around whilst I do the big refactor.

Comment: Like i read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518132/modifying-express-js-request-object, which is what i'm doing with req.cookies.Username but doesn't seem to work

Comment: Ignore above reply, i didn't re-run `npm start`. This seems to work in the demo version, will see if this works for my prod incident and if so close this post with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Modifying Express.js Request Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518132/modifying-express-js-request-object) this solves the issue.

`cookie-parser` library does not read `set-cookies` header so this is why the above code didn't work.

Instead, set a new attribute in `req` which can then be accessed under the same "request"

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());

// Function to generate a random username
function generateRandomUsername() {
  const usernameLength = 8; 
  const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  let username = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < usernameLength; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length);
    username += characters.charAt(randomIndex);
  }
  return username;
}

app.use('/hello/', function (req, res, next) {

    const username = req.cookies.Username;

    req.test = username;
  console.log("ROUTE USE: /hello/" + username);

  next();
});

app.get('/hello/username', function (req, res) {
   let username = generateRandomUsername();
    res.cookie('Username', username);

    console.log(req.test); // Shows the request set in app.use
  console.log("PATH /hello/username/ " + username);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Server listening on port 8080');
});
```